# How to know status of a elasticsearch river

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-river

I am testing elaticsearch-river-mongoDB for data transfer between from mongoDB to elasticsearch. I will be doing daily updates in mongoDB.. In this case, how can i know the status of the river..  some times i am seeing that river is stopped in the elasticsearch log. Is there any way to raise an alert if the river is not working ?

Here are the logs

```
[2015-08-31 14:39:48,047][INFO ][cluster.metadata] [slave1_dev] [[_river]] remove_mapping [[test]] 
[2015-08-31 14:39:48,086][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] Closing river test 
[2015-08-31 14:39:48,088][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] Stopping river test 
[2015-08-31 14:39:48,088][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] Stopped river test 
[2015-08-31 14:39:48,089][WARN ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] Failed to start river test –
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the logs you're seeing that make you think the river is stopped? Also can you precise which version of ES you're using?

Comment: I am using v1.4.2 of ES because of the river compatibility https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb ..

Comment: Logs:-
[2015-08-31 14:39:48,047][INFO ][cluster.metadata] [slave1_dev] [[_river]] remove_mapping [[test]]
[2015-08-31 14:39:48,086][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] Closing river test
[2015-08-31 14:39:48,088][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] Stopping river test
[2015-08-31 14:39:48,088][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] Stopped river test
[2015-08-31 14:39:48,089][WARN ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] Failed to start river test

Comment: It looks like something removes your river. Please edit your question with the steps you went through to create the river?

Comment: @Val Whatever you said is correct.. i was trying to remove a river... i just wanted to know how the rivers work ? whenever the river is unable to ping database, i am seeing above messages in ES log, so i am concerned about how to know the status of the river if the database connection is not alive.. i hope that my explanation is clear.. thanks